# What happens when Phusion PassengerMaxPoolSize is reached?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

The subject of my post pretty much sums up my question: What happens when PassengerMaxPoolSize is reached?

*For Example*:

PassengerMaxPoolSize is configured to 40 based off our system specs

What happens if **all** 40 sessions are **active (processing a request)** and our load balancer passes another session to this particular web server? This would send a 41st session to be processed without an available Passenger process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests queued.

You might want to read this http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/10/29/phusion-passenger-now-with-global-queuing/